# Drop Object on Z to Zero

Tags: python

I've been using Serpens to create my own addon, and I have this action that drops one object selected to Zero in the Z axis, and it works really nice, and I got curious to know how to do it in code.
Drop to Zero all objects selected in the Z axis.
This is how it works with the nodes:

[image]

https://streamable.com/j9jn9f
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know how the addon actually works but I think you should be able to find the generated script somewhere in the addon files

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy

objs = bpy.context.selected_objects

for obj in objs:
    obj.location.z = 0
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect!!!!! Thank you Jakemoyo!!